# Sum of totals grouped by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been out of the dev world for a few years so forgive me if this is a pretty basic question but I have an app that logs bookings for holiday accomodation. I want to produce a report detailing how much income per month a user gets.

My query thus far is as so:-

```
SELECT SUM(int_ToOwner) AS TotalIncome, 
       DateName(m,dtm_StartDate) AS BookingMonth 
FROM tbl_Bookings 
WHERE dtm_StartDate > '2021-12-31'
GROUP BY DatePart(m,dtm_StartDate), int_ToOwner, dtm_StartDate
```

But that produces the result below. I want it to give me a total for each month instead.

| TotalIncome | BookingMonth |
| --- | --- |
| 553.00 | January |
| 849.00 | January |
| 885.00 | February |
| 1236.00 | February |
| 1239.00 | February |
| 896.00 | March |
| 927.00 | March |
| 940.00 | March |
| 959.00 | March |
| 971.00 | March |
| 1167.00 | April |
| 1255.00 | April |
| 1500.00 | April |
| 2461.00 | April |
| 1131.00 | May |
| 1172.00 | May |
| 1275.00 | May |
| 2647.00 | May |
| 1466.00 | June |
| 1480.00 | June |
| 1496.00 | June |
| 1899.00 | June |
| 2167.00 | June |
| 1881.00 | July |
| 4990.00 | July |
| 4991.00 | July |
| 2134.00 | August |
| 4162.00 | August |
| 4883.00 | August |
| 5329.00 | August |
| 1430.00 | September |
| 1630.00 | October |
| 1130.00 | November |

Comment: Please add more details. Add table description, some data examples and expected result, in text format. What dbms are you using ?

Comment: Remove dtm_StartDate from GroupBy.

Comment: `GROUP BY xyz` means you want one result row per xyz. `GROUP BY DatePart(m,dtm_StartDate), int_ToOwner, dtm_StartDate` means you want one result row per month, owner and start date. But then you tell us you want one row per month only. So why this `GROUP BY` owner and start date? Are you trying to achieve something with this or is this just a mistake?

Comment: the dbms is SQL Server.....

Looks like it didnt like the difference between DatePart & DateName

SELECT SUM(int_ToOwner) AS TotalIncome, DatePart(m,dtm_StartDate) AS BookingMonth
FROM tbl_Bookings
WHERE dtm_StartDate > '2021-12-31'
GROUP BY DatePart(m,dtm_StartDate)


- works correctly except it displays the month as a number rather then a word but I can get round that on the front end

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it but you are also grouping by int_ToOwner and you have the dtm_StartDate twice.

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(int_ToOwner) AS TotalIncome, DateName(m,dtm_StartDate) AS BookingMonth
FROM tbl_Bookings 
WHERE dtm_StartDate > '2021-12-31' 
GROUP BY DatePart(m,dtm_StartDate)
```

Comment: I tried that before but get "Column 'tbl_Bookings.dtm_StartDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Correct, because you have to match terms in your SELECT which are not in an aggregation function with the terms in your GROUP BY. Read my answer and try solving the problem yourself with the info given. You'll learn more from that than copying and trying incorrect answers until the correct one pops up....

Answer (score 0):

A little re-format:

```
SELECT SUM(int_ToOwner)          AS TotalIncome
,      DateName(m,dtm_StartDate) AS BookingMonth 
FROM   tbl_Bookings 
WHERE  dtm_StartDate > '2021-12-31' 
GROUP BY DatePart(m,dtm_StartDate)
,      int_ToOwner
,      dtm_StartDate
```

Your GROUP BY tells the database to create groups for data with equal values of

- DatePart(m,dtm_StartDate)
- int_ToOwner
- dtm_StartDate

Then SELECT asks for each group the

- calculated SUM of int_ToOwner
- DateName(m,dtm_StartDate)

You should search your solution in grouping the correct attributes.